# How do I crop the size of my WebView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-webview

I am loading a `WebView Page` in one of my `NavBar` items. When I debug my app it shows me a loading screen with the `NavBar` but as soon as the `WebView` loads the `NavBar` gets hidden behind it. I'm using the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin to load the WebViews.

[image]

This is what happens after the `WebView` has loaded:
[image]

This is the code for my WebView Page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

class HomeWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeWebViewState createState() => _HomeWebViewState();
}

class _HomeWebViewState extends State<HomeWebView>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<HomeWebView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return WebviewScaffold(
      useWideViewPort: true,
      url: 'https://google.com',
    );
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Is there a way where I can crop the size of my `WebView Scaffold` so that the NavBar below is visible and functional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using SafeArea widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

class HomeWebView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeWebViewState createState() => _HomeWebViewState();
}

class _HomeWebViewState extends State<HomeWebView>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<HomeWebView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return SafeArea(
      child: WebviewScaffold(
      useWideViewPort: true,
      url: 'https://google.com',
    ));
  }

  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Comment: Hey could you also please give this similar question a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61935415/how-to-retain-webview-state-in-flutter

Comment: @SimranAswani sure